# Append option at random position in select element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
  <select>

        <option>One</option>

        <option>Two</option>

  </select>
```

I would like to append a new `option` between first and second `option` using javascript.

**Required result :**

```
 <select>

    <option> One </option>

    <option> New </option>

    <option> Two </option>

 </select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('<option> New </option>').insertBefore('select option:nth-child(2)');
```

`insertBefore` will append the element before the selector indicated. In this case we choose the 2nd child `option` of our select. Remember that `nth-child` is not zero-based index.

**JSFiddle**: https://jsfiddle.net/58209tgu/

Comment: yes,  this way, nth-child would be random, and also `insertBefor` or `insertAfter` would be randomly change

Comment: Yes, insertAfter could be used as well. Either one I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Use `eq(index)`

```
$('<option />').text('New').insertAfter('select option:eq(0)');
```

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery, you can use insertAfter function.

**Documentation:**

http://api.jquery.com/insertafter/

**Example HTML:**

```
<select>
  <option id='insertAfterMe'>One</option>
  <option>Two</option>
</select>
```

**Example jQuery:**

```
$(function(){
  $('<option>new option</option>').insertAfter('#insertAfterMe');
});
```

**jsFiddle:**

https://jsfiddle.net/fx7xxhvq/

If you don't want to put an id on the element you want to insert after, any valid selector will work, such as the nth-child selector mentioned in the other answer.